# Transforming A Complicated Expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching, rule

I am trying to transform an expression according to these rules I've defined:
$$
L_1^m L_2^n L_3^p L_4^q \rightarrow \frac{m!n!p!q!}{(m+n+p+q+3)!}6V \\ \text{constant } k \neq 0 \rightarrow kV$$
Some examples:
$$2 \rightarrow 2V \\ 3L_1 \rightarrow \frac{3V}{4} \\ 6 + 5L_1 + 7L_4^2L_1^5 \rightarrow 6V + \frac{5V}{4} + \frac{V}{360} \\ 0 + 3L_4^2 + L_1L_2^4L_3^3L_4 \rightarrow \frac{3V}{10} + \frac{V}{554400}$$

I have been briefly experimenting with `ReplaceAll` but this seems to ignore terms like $L_1L_2^4L_3^3L_4$ unless I explicitly give $L_1$ and $L_4$ a power of 1. It also seems to ignore terms like $3L_1$ and $7L_4^2L_1^5$ unless I define new (sub)rules for each of these.

What should I be doing to transform expressions like these without having to hard-code (sub)rules?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want these represented in Mathematica? Are you going to use literal L inside Subscript, Power, Times, and Plus? Also, is there a reason you're wanting to do this with replacement rules instead of with just simple function definitions?

Comment: These are essentially analytical integration rules. I want to represent L as a literal with subscripts, power, etc (even though it actually corresponds to some function). My goal is to integrate these functions using the rules I defined above to directly generate lines of code for my C++ program.

Comment: Just some small help for the case where the exponent is 1. You can include that case by using the pattern `_.`  for example compare `{L1,L1^2}/.L1^k_.->k*g` with `{L1,L1^2}/.L1^k_->k*g`. If you use `_.*b` in a pattern that means b times something or 1. If you use `b+_.` that means b plus something or 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is well-suited for replacement rules, since, among other things, you will have a hard time restricting the rules to only apply to entire terms (i.e. not stuff like the `L1` in `2*L1*L2`). That being said, you can use [`CoefficientRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html) to do most of the work for you:

```
int[expr_] := Total[
  CoefficientRules[expr, {L1, L2, L3, L4}] /. 
    ({m_, n_, p_, q_} -> a_) :> 6 a V m! n! p! q!/(m + n + p + q + 3)!
 ]
```

Note how we are effectively only post-processing the output of `CoefficientRules` with your rule, and then summing all the terms together using `Total`. Note also that there is no special rule for constants, as that is implied by the general rule. To test:

```
int[2]
(* 2 V *)

int[3 L1]
(* (3 V)/4 *)

int[6 + 5 L1 + 7 L4^2 L1^5]
(* (2611 V)/360 *)

int[0 + 3 L4^2 + L1 L2^4 L3^3 L4]
(* (166321 V)/554400 *)
```